More information needed about how univariate tern::summarize_coxph() inputs are passed to survival::coxph()

In trying to reproduce the estimates produced by the examples for summarize_coxph() in Cox proportional hazards regression using survival::coxph(), Arianna Cascone and I were able to deduce that it's necessary to supply ties = "exact" as input. Is it possible to add details about this in function's documentation?
Is it possible to add details about how the univariate and multivariate use cases differ in the documentation? From what we can tell, the univariate case takes any covariates and passes them to sequential models fitted with survival::coxph() (e.g., in the examples shown on the website, the first model contains only ARM as a predictor, the second model contains ARM + COVAR1 as predictors, and the third model contains ARM + COVAR2 as predictors, like below). Then the estimates for ARM only are extracted and presented in the outputs. However, for the multivariate use case, all predictors and covariates are passed to a single model. Is that correct?

coxph_summary1 <- summary(survival::coxph(Surv(TIME, STATUS) ~ ARM, 
                                          data = data.frame(dta_bladder), ties = "exact"))
coxph_summary1

coxph_summary2 <- summary(survival::coxph(Surv(TIME, STATUS) ~ ARM + COVAR1, 
                                          data = data.frame(dta_bladder), ties = "exact"))
coxph_summary2

coxph_summary3 <- summary(survival::coxph(Surv(TIME, STATUS) ~ ARM + COVAR2, 
                                          data = data.frame(dta_bladder), ties = "exact"))
coxph_summary3


In addition, we're a bit confused why the output from summarize_coxph() provides the hazard ratios and associated CIs/pvalues for the ARM term but the labels would imply the hazard ratios are from the covariates (indicated by "A Covariate Label" and "Sex (F/M)". Is this done because there is a primary interest in the hazard ratios for the ARM variable (thus only the corresponding hazard ratios are shown and no outputs for the covariates that are supplied)? Please see this GitHub post for the specific output in question, as I'm not able to upload an image here: https://github.com/insightsengineering/tern/issues/1267

Thank you!

I think for question 1, we added a summary with a more detail description of each function. Also if you check from ?tern::summarize_coxreg you see different connections with fit_coxreg for the specified model and control_coxreg for the supply ties. Question number 2 seems correct to me. Question 3: I think it is done for interest in the hazard rations by ARM variables, but I am not super sure

For producing the output, please consider using {reprex}
